# reading multiple excel sheets in java

Tags: java, spreadsheet, import-from-excel

I am trying to add values of multiple sheets of an Excel document to an ArrayList. without using HSSFSheet. this seems more simple think.Be careful dont forget to change string type to numeric.

```
public void setinputfile(String inputfile) {
    this.inputfile = inputfile;}

public void read() throws IOException {
    File inputWorkbook = new File(inputfile);

    try {
        Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
        int Num = w.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++) {
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(i);
            Sheet s = w.getSheet(i);
            int row = s.getRows();
            int col = s.getColumns();
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < row; i1++) {
                inner = new ArrayList<Double>();
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    Cell c = s.getCell(j, i1);
                    CellType type = c.getType();
                    System.out.println(c.getContents());
                    String text = c.getContents(); // example String
                    double value = Double.parseDouble(text);
                    inner.add(value);
                }
                Kargo_Amount.add(inner);
            }

        }
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Facility_Location test = new Facility_Location();
    test.setinputfile("C:\\Users\\soheyl\\Desktop\\Kargo miktarii.xls");
    test.read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you call getSheet(1) not getSheet(i)

Answer (score 1):

This below code is reading all sheets of xls files and you have to add jxl.jar file to this:

```
import java.io.File;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

public class ReadExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("N:\\Data\\Book1.xls");

        try {
            Workbook wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
            int Num = wb.getNumberOfSheets();

            for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++) {
                Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(i); 
                Sheet s = wb.getSheet(i);

                int row = s.getRows();
                int col = s.getColumns();

                for(int i1=0; i1<row;i1++) {
                    for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
                        Cell c =s.getCell(j, i1);
                        System.out.println(c.getContents());
                        //String text = c.getContents();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        System.out.println("completed");
    }
}
```